# Reading from AWS kinesis but using local Dynamo

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I want to read from a kinesis stream on an account where I don't have permissions to create a dynamoDB table. Im guessing that the dynamo table is to record the 'read pointer' location.

Is it possible (using AWS java libraries) to use a local instance of dynamo to do this tracking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread here: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/issues/34, shows a KCL Worker constructor that accepts a DynamoDB client.

```
public Worker( 
         com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.interfaces.IRecordProcessorFactory recordProcessorFactory, 
         KinesisClientLibConfiguration config, 
         AmazonKinesis kinesisClient, 
         AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDBClient, 
         AmazonCloudWatch cloudWatchClient, 
         ExecutorService execService) { 
     this(recordProcessorFactory, config, kinesisClient, dynamoDBClient, 
             getMetricsFactory(cloudWatchClient, config), execService); 
     if (config.getRegionName() != null) { 
         Region region = RegionUtils.getRegion(config.getRegionName()); 
         cloudWatchClient.setRegion(region); 
         LOG.debug("The region of Amazon CloudWatch client has been set to " + config.getRegionName()); 
     } 
 }
```

You can create your own DynamoDB client pointing to DynamoDB Local and initialize the KCL Worker.

You can even make this setup work for multiple KCL apps on multiple EC2 instances/containers/pods if you expose DynamoDB local to reachable over the network.